# how to start a background image 20px down?

Tags: css

I have looked around for this and it seems simple but i cant seem to work it out.

I have a div with a background.
I want the background to start 20px down and then repeat-y, as in repeat the rest of the way down.

```
<div class="main_col"></div>
.main_col {
    width: 680px;
    float: left;
    background:#fff;
    background-position:50% 50%;
}
```

This is what im trying but it is filling the whole div?

this is what i have tried....http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/gqqTM/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with one class definition in current CSS2 standards.

Use a separate div for the background.

If you want to fiddle with some CSS3, you can check out

```
background-origin
```

at
http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/

Be aware of browser support.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to add padding-top: 20px to .main_col and inside it create additional div with this background.

Answer (score 0):

```
.main_col {
    width: 680px;
    float: left;
    background: url("your image") 0px 20px;        
}
```

**Update**

this is  using **giker** s example
try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/88FZ6/2/)

Comment: + 1 this is the best solution - it won't affect any padding or margin. Just set the background right. This is like I would do, too.

Comment: @Beginner:where is the **image** ??

Comment: im using colour as an example for now

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 CSS properties relevant to achieving this:

1. `background-image { url(/myBackground.png) }` // To select the image
2. `background-repeat { no-repeat }` // To choose how or if it repeats
3. `background-position { 1px 1px }` // To choose the X, Y coordinates of the top left corner of the background image in relation to the top left corner of the element.

Now, that's all quite verbose but it can be condensed into a single rule, as follows:

```
background { url(myBackground.png) no-repeat 1px 1px }
```

It is possible to use relative values (such as the % which your code shows) for the background-position, but you will need to use px.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a <strike>margin</strike> padding.

i.e.

```
.main_col {
    width: 680px;
    float: left;
    background:#fff;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: your code will drop the whole div 20px down..not the background image

Comment: indeed, the desired effect is the inner content only. then padding is appropriate.

Comment: you can't use padding either...it will make space from top but background image will start from top. If you need to use **padding** or **margin** you will need to use another div